# Convert string with comma to float with dot

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("X" + 
    characterPosition["position.x"] + 
    " XC: " + 
    (float)Convert.ToDouble(characterPosition["position.x"]));
```

This prints:

```
X140,9671 XC: 1409671
```

How can I convert the string `140,9671` to be float like `140.9671`?

Comment: `,` is the decimal separator in many cultures and is apparently the current one on your computer. If you want to output a specific format, you can do that explicitly with format parameters.

Comment: That depends...what is being returned by `characterPosition["position.x"]`?  Is it a **string** or a **numeric type**?

Comment: Two duplicates cover all possible combinations of parse/format dot/comma... Side note: disagreeing how your machine is configured to show floating point numbers is not really on-topic on SO... If that's your actual question (how to configure floating point formatting in Windows/Linux) SU would be better place to ask.